# In laravel, how do I generate an array of counts?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

For example, I have several orders, and each order is related to a zone(there are 10 zones). I want the number of orders for each zone so 10 rows. Something like this:

```
Select count(*) as aggregate from orders group by zone_id
```

I tried using count and groupby methods but it generates an integer.

```
Order::groupBy('zone_id')->count();
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: count(*) is return integer too right?

Comment: yes the above code returns an integer in the 1st row only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using withCount - [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models)

You will need to add a relationship in your zone model, add the following

```
class Zone extends Model
{
     public function orders()
     {
         return $this->hasMany(Order::class);
     }
}
```

The eloquent query - the "orders" is the name of the method in your model (above)

```
$zones = Zone::withCount('orders')->get();
```

Then in your blade file

```
@foreach($zones as $zone)
    {{ $zone->name }} --- {{ $zone->orders_count }}
@endfoeach
```

Comment: Yes thank you that solved it ! I used pluck with the method you mentioned i only need the count. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Laravel's `count()` is not the same as SQL's count. So you have to use it via Laravel's `select()`:

```php
Order::select(DB::raw('COUNT(*) as aggregate'))->groupBy('zone_id')->pluck('aggregate');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```
Order::selectRaw('*, COUNT(*) as aggregate')->groupBy('zone_id')->get();
```